# $x$-Intercept of a Line Parallel to the $x$-Axis

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, algebra-precalculus

I have a line $y = b$.

My professor and I both agree on the fact that the **$y$-intercept has to be *$b$*** in value.
However, this morning we had an argument on the $x$-intercept of this line.

He is of the opinion that a line parallel to the $x$-axis should never intersect with it; therefore, its $x$-intercept should be zero and its $y$-intercept should be $b$.

I felt the $x$-intercept must be tending towards infinity or undefined in value.
In accordance with the *Intercept Form of the Equation of a Line*,
$x/a + y/b = 1$

Therefore, for the line $y = b$, one may rewrite it as $y/b = 1$. Since there is no $x$-term in this equation, one may assume $x/a = 0$ to make the Intercept Form hold true.

$x/a = 0$ and therefore $a = x/0$. Thus, the **$x$-intercept is tending to infinity / undefined**.
He feels my solution is wrong for he has the opinion that no line can have an $x$-intercept which tends to infinity; he feels it is not possible, but I beg to differ.

I'm looking for clarity on this topic. It's been at the back of my mind the whole day and I have no idea if my solution to this problem is correct.
***Is the $x$-intercept of a line parallel to the $x$-axis zero or tending towards infinity?***

Comment: This line does not have an x-intercept.  It does not intersect the x-axis, so there is no x-intercept.

Comment: The $~x~$ intercept(s) is/are defined to be the point(s) where the line intersects the $~x$-axis.  If the line is not parallel to the $~x$-axis, then the $~x$-intercept will be unique.  If the line is parallel to the $~x$-axis, but is not equal to the $~x$-axis (i.e. $y = 0~$), then there is no $~x$-intercept.  In such a situation, construing the $~x$-intercept to be $~0~$ is wrong.  An example of a line with the $~x$-intercept $~= 0~$ would be $~y = x.$  The syntax "tends toward infinity" seems like a convoluted way of saying simply that there is no $~x$-intercept.

Comment: As others said, the $x$-int of a fixed line doesn't "tend" to anything. Yet, the $x$-ints of a *family* of lines (say, through a given pt) can tend to ... well ... It depends: $x$-ints of lines w/vanishingly-small *positive* slopes tend to "$-\infty$"; those of lines w/ *negative* slopes tend to "$+\infty$". With two (*very*) distinct candidates, "the" (single) $x$-int can't be named; hence, "undefined". That said, it *can* be intuitively helpful to describe the $x$-int of a horizontal line as "infinite"; eg, $y=b$ is a special case of $x/a+y/b=1$, since "infinite" $a$ kills the first term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the right question to ask is *when does a line **NOT** have an $x$ intercept*?

In the simplest of terms an intercept, in this case the $x$ intercept is a *solution* to two *simultaneous linear equations*, which as we all know is a *point* where, to keep it simple, *two* lines intersect.

We have have on equation, your line $y = b$. For simplicity let's say $b = 4$ and so the line is $y = 4$

The other line we're interested in is the $x$ axis, $y = 0$

Can you find a solution for the two simultaneous linear equations below?

1. $y = 4$
2. $y = 0$

Bonam Fortunam, homo viator!

Answer (score 3):

A horizontal line does not cross the x-axis, therefore, it does not have an x-intercept. Its x-intercept is undefined. To say a line has an x-intercept of 0 implies that the line crosses the x-axis at x=0, which obviously is not the case for a horizontal line. I also wouldn't say its intercept "tends to infinity", as a line with fixed slope doesn't tend toward anything. At most, you could say that as a line's slope tends toward 0, its x-intercept tends toward +/- infinity.

I don't really follow the professor's line of thinking, he merely pre-supposes that a line that does not intersect the x-axis has an x-intercept of zero with no rationale whatsoever. He is arguing that the line intersects the x-axis at x=0, despite the fact that the line *never* intersects the x-axis.

Comment: Ah alright, I understood now.
Thankyou so much for this explanation, this really helped.

Answer (score 1):

> its $x$-intercept should be zero

That is incorrect, since if $a=0$, $(a,0)=(0,0)$ is not on the line.

> the $x$-intercept is tending to infinity / undefined

"The $x$-intercept is tending to infinity" doesn't make sense here. Tending as what variable changes? Not $x$ and not $y$. Maybe as $m \to 0$, but that's an unnecessarily complicated way of looking at this.

"The $x$-intercept is undefined" is better...

But what we usually say here is "the line **does not have** an $x$-intercept".

Comment: Oh alright. I just started with precalc and I thought 'undefined' and 'tending to infinity' meant the same thing. I used to use the terms interchangeably. Thankyou for this explanation; it helped me understand the difference now.